# redirect problems with authorization in strava.com using scrapy. Log says that strava redirects me from /login to /dashboard to /login

Tags: python, redirect, scrapy, web-crawler, strava

I really need your help: tried already everything! The goal - authorize the https://www.strava.com/login using scrapy.

That's my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class StravaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'strava'
   start_urls = ('https://www.strava.com/dashboard',)
   #handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302]


   def parse(self, response):
       token = response.xpath('//*[@name="csrf-token"]/@content').get()
       return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formdata={
                                            'authenticity_token': token,
                                            'plan': "",
                                            'email': 'login',
                                            'password': 'password'},
                                        #dont_filter=True,
                                        #meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]},
                                        callback=self.scrape_page)

   def scrape_page(self, response):
       print('okkkk', '\n\n\n\n')
       open_in_browser(response)
```

The problem is in redirecting:

```
2020-08-16 20:18:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.strava.com/dashboard> from <POST https://www.strava.com/session>
2020-08-16 20:18:49 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36
2020-08-16 20:18:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.strava.com/login> from <GET https://www.strava.com/dashboard>
2020-08-16 20:18:49 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
2020-08-16 20:18:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.strava.com/dashboard> from <GET https://www.strava.com/login>
2020-08-16 20:18:50 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.strava.com/dashboard> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2020-08-16 20:18:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

The Form data in Request Headers of post request is utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=W28zQ9XWLK7oktgDzUj0kCozODXk2bJQLAqPihwEJ8gwj1VDKtA7c5AWwTw0OUovnyAZkcXiNdF2Zt4AsNOIUQ%3D%3D&plan=&email=&password= –

If I uncomment `don't filter=True` and make `handle_httpstatus_list = [302]` It returns me a very interesting page:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>You are being <a href="https://www.strava.com/dashboard">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

And if I make a mistake in a password or login - it really goes to callback function and returns me a page with 'The username or password did not match. Please try again.' It means that my authorization works, but scrapy doesn't follow right page.

I turned off duplicate filter, added handle_httpstatus_list, added scrapy-redirect in settings....nothing works. Please no bs4 or selenium - I've already did this program with them, now I need only scrapy and this authorization...makes me cry

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1225

Comment: @Gallaecio - no((

Comment: I would guess cookies are not being set or interpreted correctly, or your random U-A Middleware is jamming up their session fixing algorithm

Comment: @mdaniel I think the same about cookies, but how to fix it...none of the ideas were successful

Comment: well, do you have [`COOKIES_ENABLED = True`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.3/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std-setting-COOKIES_ENABLED) in your `settings.py` (and perhaps `COOKIES_DEBUG=True` also)? have you inspected the Request and Response objects to see if they contain the same headers as does your browser?

Comment: @mdaniel. Cookies are enabled by default. I turned on cookies debug and now get this: https://pastebin.com/NXyV1BgJ . THIS CODE WORKED ONE TIME but no more...: https://pastebin.com/Q2eqL5fj

Comment: Have you tried removing the random U-A middleware and see if the behavior continues? Does your browser do that cookie exchange, or only Scrapy?

Comment: @mdaniel - same situation(